# getting sharepoint list dropdown value using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, powershell-script

I'm trying to get a sharepoint list choice field value using powershell. The choice field contains a yes and no values. now I want to check if it's a Yes and do some logic.

```
foreach($item in $listItems) 
{     
               $value= $list.items | where {$item["Exported)"] -eq $item["Exported)"]."Yes"
               if($value)
               {
                $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject 
                $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Date" -value $item["Date"]
                $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Employer" -value $item["Employer"]
                $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Employer Number" -value $item["Employer Number"]
                $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Classification" -value $item["Classification"]
                $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Source" -value $item["Source"]
                $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Action" -value $item["Action"]
                $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Description" -value $item["Description"]
                $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Exported" -value $item["Exported"]

                $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
                $ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "C:\Users\Documents\CSV uotput\Test.CSV" -NoTypeInformation
               }
}
```

this exports the data regardless whether the choice field is a "No", what I want to export items that have the choice field as "Yes"

*Please assist.*

Answer (score 1):

Multiple things that seems of with your code. "Exported" has a `)` in it's name. Followed by `.` + the string to check against.

You need to declare `$ListItemCollection` as an array to be able to push multiple values to it. But I think you already have but it's not in the part of your script that you provided.

It's always good to set the parameters `delimiter` and `encoding` for your CSV, if you wanna be able to work further with your data.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "WebNameGoesHere"

$list = $web.Lists["ListNameGoesHere"]

$ListItemCollection = @()

foreach($item in $list.Items) {  

    if($item["Exported"] -eq "Yes") {

        $ExportItem = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date" -value $item["Date"]
        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Employeer" -value $item["Employer"]
        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Employee Number" -value $item["Employer Number"]
        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Classification" -value $item["Classification"]
        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Source" -value $item["Source"]
        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Action" -value $item["Action"]
        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Description" -value $item["Description"]
        $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Exported" -value $item["Exported"]

        $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
    }
}
$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Users\Documents\CSV output\Test.CSV" -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

I would also recommend to use `test-path` before exporting data to a CSV, to make sure that the path actually exists and create it if it don't.

```
$exportPath = "C:\Users\Documents\CSV output"

If(!(test-path $exportPath ))
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $exportPath | Out-Null
}

Export-CSV -Path "$exportPath \Test.CSV"
```